# Nodejs Access problem on wsl bash terminal in windows

Tags: node.js

I installed nodejs stable version in windows 10 pro. But I can't access it (nodejs) in wsl ubuntu bash terminal on windows 10. I am newbie. Help me.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please add to your question which kind of error are you receiving so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use **NodeJS in WSL**, you need to install it in the WSL itself. Sharing of windows application directly in WSL is not possible as both are two different environments.
Also, you can use the NodeJS installed in WSL2 along with Visual studio code for developing web applications with ease.
If you want to install NodeJS in WSL2 use these:

The complete instruction can be found here [set-up-on-wsl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/nodejs/setup-on-wsl2)

If you are too busy to follow the link, follow these steps in the WSL:

1. Use curl to install nvm

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash
```

2. For installing NodeJs (lts)

```
nvm install node --lts
```

3. You can also install specific node version. Check all commands uses by typing `nvm` in your terminal.
4. Done Node has been successfully installed in your WSL,  `nvm ls` will list all the installations.

You can use the Node installed in your WSL for developing. Point to your working directory and use `code .` to open VSCode (if installed in your windows machine). Also, if you want to access your windows directories you can mount them by using `/mnt/<dir>`

Also note that, the Node installed in the WSL can only be used, iff your working directory is in the WSL or is linked with your WSL(by using `mnt`).